# Merge sort implementation with an array used instead of vector

Tags: c++, mergesort

I am trying to implement a `merge-sort` algorithm with the use of `arrays` instead of `vectors` and I am getting some errors in one of my two functions. The code of the two functions is below.

```
void Merge(int ar[], int ar1[], int ar2[], int n1, int n2) {

    int p1 = 0;
    int p2 = 0;
    int p3 = 0;
    while (p1 < n1 && p2 < n2) {
        if (ar1[p1] < ar2[p2])
        {
            ar[p3]=ar1[p1];
            p3++;
            p1++;
        }
        else
        {
            ar[p3]=ar2[p2];
            p3++;
            p2++;
        }
    }

    while (p1 < n1)
    {
        ar[p3]=ar1[p1];
        p3++;
        p1++;
    }

    while (p2 < n2)
    {
        ar[p3]=ar2[p2];
        p3++;
        p2++;
    }
}
```

---

I figured out how to solve the problem I was facing with the code below.

```
void Sortmerge(int array[],int n) {

    if (n <= 1) return;

    if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        int arr1[n/2];
        int arr2[n/2];
        int k=0;
        int l=0;

        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if (i<(n/2))
            {
                arr1[k++]=array[i];
            }

            else
            {
                arr2[l++]=array[i];
            }
        }

        Sortmerge(arr1,n/2);
        Sortmerge(arr2,n/2);

        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        array[i]=0;
        }

        Merge(array, arr1, arr2,n/2,n/2);
    }

    if (n%2!=0)
    {
        int arr1[(n-1)/2];
        int arr2[(n+1)/2];
        int k=0;
        int l=0;
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if (i<((n-1)/2))
            {
                arr1[k++]=array[i];
            }

            else
            {
                arr2[l++]=array[i];
            }
        }

        Sortmerge(arr1,(n-1)/2);
        Sortmerge(arr2,(n+1)/2);

        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            array[i]=0;
        }

        Merge(array, arr1, arr2,(n-1)/2,(n+1)/2 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that variable-size arrays aren't standard C++ so some compilers won't accept them. Looks like you're using gcc which does.

Comment: `sizeof(ar1)/sizeof(int)` doesn't do what you want, since `sizeof(ar1)` is the same as `sizeof(int*)`

Answer (score 3):

You have declared two sets of arrays. Two named `arr1` and two named `arr2`. These have some data added to them, but then they go out of scope and the data is not used. That is the source of the warnings.

You then attempt to use `arr1` and `arr2` out of their scopes -- outside of the if blocks. This is the source of the error. These arrays must be declared once, likely at the top of your function (`Sortmerge`), before your `n % 2` checks.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
if (n%2==0)
{
    int arr1[n/2]; //<-------here
    int arr2[n/2]; //<-------here
    ..........
}
```

`arr1` and `arr2` are only visible to code within that scope (between the `{}`s). So you have two different sets of `arr1` and `arr2`, one for odd `n` and one for even `n`, but neither of those is visible to your `Sortmerge(...)` calls.

Also, you can replace

```
if (n%2==0){
....
}

if (n%2!=0){
....
}
```

with

```
if (n%2==0){
....
}
else{
....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's seem normal.

You declare your two array in a **if** statement. The scope for your variable is just for this statement.
Replace :

```
   if (n%2==0)
    {
        int arr1[n/2]; //<-------here
        int arr2[n/2]; //<-------here
        int k=0;
        int l=0;
```

by

```
   int arr1[n/2]; //<-------here
   int arr2[n/2]; //<-------here
   if (n%2==0)
    {
        int k=0;
        int l=0;
```